# Can Bazel hide host files completely from build actions?

Tags: bazel, sandbox

I want to hide all irrelevant source files from build actions because there are some tools that explore host file system, for example, `node` searches `node_modules` directory from working directory to root `/`. But `linux-sandbox` doesn't seem to hide host files outside the sandboxes:

```
genrule(
    name = "foo",
    outs = ["x"],
    cmd = "ls ~ | tee $@",
)
```

Outputs:

```
<my home files>
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/x
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.088s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
```

According to [the official doc](https://bazel.build/docs/sandboxing), `linux-sandbox` makes host files read-only but doesn't hide them.

Is there any way to hide host files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can make a host path inaccessible in the linux sandbox with [`--sandbox_block_path`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--sandbox_block_path).

It's also possible to remove all host directories from the sandbox except ones explicitly added with `--sandbox_add_mount_pair` by employing the [`--experimental_use_hermetic_linux_sandbox`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--experimental_use_hermetic_linux_sandbox) flag.